# Flutter Error in bash after running flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

When I have run this command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

I got this error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
```

Do anyone has an idea about this problem , I have googled it and stackoverflowed it but without any result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also share your OS version and Java version?

Comment: java 15 and windows 10

Comment: https://flutteragency.com/fix-android-license-status-unknown/ 

perhaps steps in this article can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Installed Flutter properly and updated to latest,
And run
`flutter doctor -v`
check stats
If that does not work install flutter again,
Check tutorial for help for your Environment